# How to forward call with music using Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I need help in "Twilio Studio - Forward Call with playing music until user pickup the call"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build out the logic yourself, you can borrow pretty heavily from the blog below, which placed the incoming user into a conference until some generic long running async operation (possibly your call forwarding logic) is completed:

[Gracefully Handle Long Running Asynchronous Operations in Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/handle-long-running-asynchronous-operations-studio)